# Some questions about resolving multiplt Spring View Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a couple questions about Spring MVC **View Resolvers**. Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-viewresolver-chaining

1. What happens when there is no `order` property set for a particular view resolver?
2. What does the document mean by `an InternalResourceViewResolver, which is always automatically positioned as the last resolver in the chain`? Does it mean that the `InternalResourceViewResolver` should **always** be given the highest `order` as a convention, or maybe Spring implicitly enforces that this resolver must always be loaded last and thus the `order` property is not required?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when there is no order property set for a particular view resolver?

The collection of `ViewResolvers` will be sorted using a `OrderComparator`. If it has no order (does not implement `Ordered`) it will receive `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`.

> What does the document mean by an InternalResourceViewResolver, which is always automatically positioned as the last resolver in the chain? Does it mean that the InternalResourceViewResolver should always be given the highest order as a convention, or maybe Spring implicitly enforces that this resolver must always be loaded last and thus the order property is not required?

`InternalResourceViewResolver` is forcefully positioned as last in the chain because it will always return a view no matter if it exists or not rendering any `ViewResolver` next in the chain unreachable.

---

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html

> Note: When chaining ViewResolvers, an InternalResourceViewResolver always needs to be last, as it will attempt to resolve any view name, no matter whether the underlying resource actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Do you know where in the documentation it mentions these?